# How to make Intl.NumberFormat have the same output on Chrome and Safari?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

```js
new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    notation: "compact",
    compactDisplay: "long",
  }).format(1547150626.57);
```

outputs `1.55 billion` on Chrome and `1.5 billion` on Safari.

I want it to always display two decimals: `1.55 billion`.

I tried the above code and I expected it to display the same number in all browser.

Comment: What version of Safari? I get the expected output on Version 16.4 (18615.1.26.110.1)

Comment: I get a different results from Safari v16.0 (17614.1.25.9.10, 17614) as well.